# RSA Signature generated by X-Cube Crypto Library (Embedded C) and Python script are not matching even though we used same key for both methods

Tags: c, python-3.x, cryptography, embedded, rsa

My application to generate SHA256 hash value for the "xx_xx.hex " file and then generate RSA signature for hash . SHA256 value generated by X-Cube-CRYPTOLIB and python script both are same. But RSA signature is not same.

i created 1024 key pair by using "openssl".Hash value is generated by X-Cube-CRYPTOLIB is in decimal format , But it is equivalent to generated hash value (hex format) by python script .

Generated SHA256 value is: 5b4c333945c47a952bfe1571e5b58b4674985fa754f19abcb5739f4c2dda433b

But the signature which is generated X-Cube-CRYPTOLIB decimal values are not equivalent to the generated signature (hex format ) by python script.

Below is the result of python script;

Hexadecimal signature: 72869266541a76bc2a73437e53c1c917e4b2dd323f8b9735e44f6d600e7fe414c0899e41e0a89c557bcd3673dac2084409fabb0ef52574108363fdd3bdc44d2239371fe3e0617966f93964db42d12ad91b254b70af7add8cd1043d7f6a5857ea834c885480d5ac2d792c514233fcc62eea3149fc8fa50e0e2579f780ff6e1c37

Please find the below image to check signature generated by X-Cube-CRYPTOLIB, it is not complete.But just for reference we can see few bytes.
[computed singature X-Cube-CRYPTOLIB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo0Bk.jpg)

Python script:

```
import hashlib
import sys
from intelhex import IntelHex
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding, rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
import os
import binascii

 
# Path to the hex file you want to load
file_path  = 'W:/xxx/xxx/xxx_input.hex'
privkey_path = 'W:/xxx/xxx/rivate_1024key.pem'
pubkey_path = 'W:/xxx/xxx/public_1024key.pem'
output_file = 'W:/xxx/xxx//Hash.txt'
outhex_file = 'W:/xxx/xxx/xxx_output.hex'

# Define the ranges() function
def ranges(addresses):
    start = addresses[0]
    end = addresses[0]
    for address in addresses[1:]:
        if address == end + 1:
            end = address
        else:
            yield start, end
            start = address
            end = address
    yield start, end

# Load the Intel Hex file
hex = IntelHex(file_path)

# Get the sorted list of addresses
addresses = hex.addresses()
addresses.sort()

# Iterate over address ranges and extract the data
data_list = list(ranges(addresses))
for start, end in data_list:
    size = end - start + 1
    data = list(hex.tobinarray(start=start, size=size)) 
    # Convert the data to hexadecimal format
    hex_data = ''.join(format(byte, '02x') for byte in data)  
    data_bytes = bytes.fromhex(hex_data)
    hasher = hashlib.sha256()
    hasher.update(data_bytes)
    hash_value = hasher.hexdigest()
    # Print the hash value in hexadecimal format
    print("SHA256 Hash Value:", hash_value)
    # Digest to be signed
    # Convert the hash value to bytes
    digest_bytes = bytes.fromhex(hash_value)

   
    # Load the private key from file
try:
    with open(privkey_path, 'rb') as f:
        private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        f.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
    print("private_key:", private_key)
    # If no exception occurred, the private key was loaded successfully
    print("Private key loaded successfully.")

    # Use the private key for signing or other operations
    
except Exception as e:
    print("Error loading private key:", e)


# Save the digest bytes to a file
with open(output_file, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(digest_bytes)
    print("Digest:", digest_bytes)


# Sign the digest with the private key
signature = private_key.sign(
    digest_bytes,
    padding.PKCS1v15(),  # Use PKCS1v15 padding scheme for RSA signatures
    hashes.SHA256()  # Use SHA256 hashing algorithm
)

# Convert the signature to hexadecimal format if needed
hex_signature = signature.hex()

# Print the hexadecimal signature
print("Hexadecimal signature:", hex_signature)
```

C Code of X-Cube:

```
const uint8_t Message[] =
{
  0xcd, 0xc8, 0x7d, 0xa2, 0x23, 0xd7, 0x86, 0xdf, 0x3b, 0x45, 0xe0, 0xbb, 0xbc, 0x72, 0x13, 0x26,
  0xd1, 0xee, 0x2a, 0xf8, 0x06, 0xcc, 0x31, 0x54, 0x75, 0xcc, 0x6f, 0x0d, 0x9c, 0x66, 0xe1, 0xb6,
  0x23, 0x71, 0xd4, 0x5c, 0xe2, 0x39, 0x2e, 0x1a, 0xc9, 0x28, 0x44, 0xc3, 0x10, 0x10, 0x2f, 0x15,
  0x6a, 0x0d, 0x8d, 0x52, 0xc1, 0xf4, 0xc4, 0x0b, 0xa3, 0xaa, 0x65, 0x09, 0x57, 0x86, 0xcb, 0x76,
  0x97, 0x57, 0xa6, 0x56, 0x3b, 0xa9, 0x58, 0xfe, 0xd0, 0xbc, 0xc9, 0x84, 0xe8, 0xb5, 0x17, 0xa3,
  0xd5, 0xf5, 0x15, 0xb2, 0x3b, 0x8a, 0x41, 0xe7, 0x4a, 0xa8, 0x67, 0x69, 0x3f, 0x90, 0xdf, 0xb0,
  0x61, 0xa6, 0xe8, 0x6d, 0xfa, 0xae, 0xe6, 0x44, 0x72, 0xc0, 0x0e, 0x5f, 0x20, 0x94, 0x57, 0x29,
  0xcb, 0xeb, 0xe7, 0x7f, 0x06, 0xce, 0x78, 0xe0, 0x8f, 0x40, 0x98, 0xfb, 0xa4, 0x1f, 0x9d, 0x61,
  0x93, 0xc0, 0x31, 0x7e, 0x8b, 0x60, 0xd4, 0xb6, 0x08, 0x4a, 0xcb, 0x42, 0xd2, 0x9e, 0x38, 0x08,
  0xa3, 0xbc, 0x37, 0x2d, 0x85, 0xe3, 0x31, 0x17, 0x0f, 0xcb, 0xf7, 0xcc, 0x72, 0xd0, 0xb7, 0x1c,
  0x29, 0x66, 0x48, 0xb3, 0xa4, 0xd1, 0x0f, 0x41, 0x62, 0x95, 0xd0, 0x80, 0x7a, 0xa6, 0x25, 0xca,
  0xb2, 0x74, 0x4f, 0xd9, 0xea, 0x8f, 0xd2, 0x23, 0xc4, 0x25, 0x37, 0x02, 0x98, 0x28, 0xbd, 0x16,
  0xbe, 0x02, 0x54, 0x6f, 0x13, 0x0f, 0xd2, 0xe3, 0x3b, 0x93, 0x6d, 0x26, 0x76, 0xe0, 0x8a, 0xed,
  0x1b, 0x73, 0x31, 0x8b, 0x75, 0x0a, 0x01, 0x67, 0xd0
};
const uint8_t Known_Signature[] =
{
  0x6b, 0xc3, 0xa0, 0x66, 0x56, 0x84, 0x29, 0x30, 0xa2, 0x47, 0xe3, 0x0d, 0x58, 0x64, 0xb4, 0xd8,
  0x19, 0x23, 0x6b, 0xa7, 0xc6, 0x89, 0x65, 0x86, 0x2a, 0xd7, 0xdb, 0xc4, 0xe2, 0x4a, 0xf2, 0x8e,
  0x86, 0xbb, 0x53, 0x1f, 0x03, 0x35, 0x8b, 0xe5, 0xfb, 0x74, 0x77, 0x7c, 0x60, 0x86, 0xf8, 0x50,
  0xca, 0xef, 0x89, 0x3f, 0x0d, 0x6f, 0xcc, 0x2d, 0x0c, 0x91, 0xec, 0x01, 0x36, 0x93, 0xb4, 0xea,
  0x00, 0xb8, 0x0c, 0xd4, 0x9a, 0xac, 0x4e, 0xcb, 0x5f, 0x89, 0x11, 0xaf, 0xe5, 0x39, 0xad, 0xa4,
  0xa8, 0xf3, 0x82, 0x3d, 0x1d, 0x13, 0xe4, 0x72, 0xd1, 0x49, 0x05, 0x47, 0xc6, 0x59, 0xc7, 0x61,
  0x7f, 0x3d, 0x24, 0x08, 0x7d, 0xdb, 0x6f, 0x2b, 0x72, 0x09, 0x61, 0x67, 0xfc, 0x09, 0x7c, 0xab,
  0x18, 0xe9, 0xa4, 0x58, 0xfc, 0xb6, 0x34, 0xcd, 0xce, 0x8e, 0xe3, 0x58, 0x94, 0xc4, 0x84, 0xd7
};

const uint8_t Modulus[] =
{
  0xa5, 0x6e, 0x4a, 0x0e, 0x70, 0x10, 0x17, 0x58, 0x9a, 0x51, 0x87, 0xdc, 0x7e, 0xa8, 0x41, 0xd1,
  0x56, 0xf2, 0xec, 0x0e, 0x36, 0xad, 0x52, 0xa4, 0x4d, 0xfe, 0xb1, 0xe6, 0x1f, 0x7a, 0xd9, 0x91,
  0xd8, 0xc5, 0x10, 0x56, 0xff, 0xed, 0xb1, 0x62, 0xb4, 0xc0, 0xf2, 0x83, 0xa1, 0x2a, 0x88, 0xa3,
  0x94, 0xdf, 0xf5, 0x26, 0xab, 0x72, 0x91, 0xcb, 0xb3, 0x07, 0xce, 0xab, 0xfc, 0xe0, 0xb1, 0xdf,
  0xd5, 0xcd, 0x95, 0x08, 0x09, 0x6d, 0x5b, 0x2b, 0x8b, 0x6d, 0xf5, 0xd6, 0x71, 0xef, 0x63, 0x77,
  0xc0, 0x92, 0x1c, 0xb2, 0x3c, 0x27, 0x0a, 0x70, 0xe2, 0x59, 0x8e, 0x6f, 0xf8, 0x9d, 0x19, 0xf1,
  0x05, 0xac, 0xc2, 0xd3, 0xf0, 0xcb, 0x35, 0xf2, 0x92, 0x80, 0xe1, 0x38, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0x64, 0xc4,
  0xef, 0x22, 0xe1, 0xe1, 0xf2, 0x0d, 0x0c, 0xe8, 0xcf, 0xfb, 0x22, 0x49, 0xbd, 0x9a, 0x21, 0x37
};
const uint8_t Public_Exponent[] =
{
  0x01, 0x00, 0x01
};
const uint8_t Private_Exponent[] =
{
  0x33, 0xa5, 0x04, 0x2a, 0x90, 0xb2, 0x7d, 0x4f, 0x54, 0x51, 0xca, 0x9b, 0xbb, 0xd0, 0xb4, 0x47,.......};
const uint8_t P_Prime[] =
{
  0xe7, 0xe8, 0x94, 0x27, 0x20, 0xa8, 0x77, 0x51, 0x72, 0x73, 0xa3, 0x56, 0x05, 0x3e, 0xa2, 0xa1,....};
const uint8_t Q_Prime[] =
{
  0xb6, 0x9d, 0xca, 0x1c, 0xf7, 0xd4, 0xd7, 0xec, 0x81, 0xe7, 0x5b, 0x90, 0xfc, 0xca, 0x87, 0x4a, ..........};
const uint8_t P_Prime_Exponent[] =
{
  0x28, 0xfa, 0x13, 0x93, 0x86, 0x55, 0xbe, 0x1f, 0x8a, 0x15, 0x9c, 0xba, 0xca, 0x5a, 0x72, 0xea,.............};
const uint8_t Q_Prime_Exponent[] =
{
  0x1a, 0x8b, 0x38, 0xf3, 0x98, 0xfa, 0x71, 0x20, 0x49, 0x89, 0x8d, 0x7f, 0xb7, 0x9e, 0xe0, 0xa7,....};
const uint8_t Coefficient[] =
{
  0x27, 0x15, 0x6a, 0xba, 0x41, 0x26, 0xd2, 0x4a, 0x81, 0xf3, 0xa5, 0x28, 0xcb, 0xfb, 0x27, 0xf5,... };

    uint8_t Computed_Signature[128];

    uint8_t computed_hash[CMOX_SHA256_SIZE];

    const uint8_t Public_Exponent[] = {0x01, 0x00, 0x01};

    uint8_t Working_Buffer[3500];

    StartAddress = 0x0802A000;
    EndAddress = 0x0802FF00;

    /* Compute directly the digest passing all the needed parameters */
hretval = cmox_hash_compute(CMOX_SHA256_ALGO, /* Use SHA256 algorithm */
                            const uint8_t*)(uintptr_t)StartAddress,
                            (EndAddress - StartAddress + 1), /* Message to digest */
                             computed_hash,    /* Data buffer to receive digest data */
                             CMOX_SHA256_SIZE, /* Expected digest size */
                             &computed_size);  /* Size of computed digest *

/* Construct a RSA context, specifying mathematics implementation and working buffer for later processing */
cmox_rsa_construct(&Rsa_Ctx, CMOX_RSA_MATH_FUNCS, CMOX_MODEXP_PRIVATE, Working_Buffer, sizeof(Working_Buffer));

retval = cmox_rsa_setKeyCRTwithFACM(&Rsa_Key,                                   /* RSA key structure to fill */
                                    sizeof(Modulus) * 8,                        /* Private key modulus bit length */
                                    P_Prime_Exponent, sizeof(P_Prime_Exponent), /* P prime */
                                    Q_Prime_Exponent, sizeof(Q_Prime_Exponent), /* Q prime */
                                    P_Prime, sizeof(P_Prime),                   /* P prime exponent */
                                    Q_Prime, sizeof(Q_Prime),                   /* Q prime exponent */
                                    Coefficient, sizeof(Coefficient),           /* Coefficient */
                                    Public_Exponent, sizeof(Public_Exponent));  /* Public exponent */

/* Compute directly the signature passing all the needed parameters */
retval = cmox_rsa_pkcs1v15_sign(&Rsa_Ctx,                            /* RSA context */
                                &Rsa_Key,                            /* RSA key to use */
                                computed_hash,                       /* Digest to sign */
                                CMOX_RSA_PKCS1V15_HASH_SHA256,       /* Method used to compute the digest */
                                Computed_Signature, &computed_size); /* Data buffer to receive signature */
```

in script I used PKCS1v15 padding scheme for RSA signature, Which is similar to C code. But still the signatures are not same.

Please suggest what is the wrong here. might be any data format conversion or double hashing or something else?

Comment: Your pyca/cryptography implementation seems to hash twice (implicitly and explicitly), which is probably not intended. Check if this is consistent with the X Cube side (I don't know X Cube). If one side hashes twice and the other one hashes once, the result will be different signatures.

Comment: RSA/PKCS#1 v1.5 padding is deterministic, i.e. the same message and the same key result in the same signature. However, there are also paddings that are non-deterministic, e.g. RSA/PSS. For verification to be successful, the signing and verifying sides must use the *same* padding.

Comment: Actually you only need to pass the original data (`data_bytes`) instead of the hashed data (`digest_bytes`). Also, the pyca/cryptography documentation is pretty good: there you will find two code snippets in the [Signing chapter](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#signing) (the examples apply PSS, but the same is true for PKCS#1 v1.5). The first example expects the original data, the second example the already hashed data. In both cases, hashing is done only once.

Comment: @Topaco: Thank you for the input . I will try the examples. I want to sign for the data which is already hashed. Do I need to convert the digest_bytes to hexadecimal and then use it for signature?

Comment: Usually the raw data is signed, i.e. `data_bytes` if the function hashes implicitly (s. the 1st snippet) or `digest_bytes` if the function requires the already hashed data (s. the 2nd snippet).

Comment: @Topaco: I tried 2nd snippet code, But still RSA signature is not same. My raw data is message ´= "cdc87da223d786df3b45e0bbbc721326d1ee2af806cc315475cc6f0d9c66e1b62371d45ce2392e1ac92844c310102f156a0d8d52c1f4c40ba3aa65095786cb769757a6563ba958fed0bcc984e8b517a3d5f515b23b8a41e74aa867693f90dfb061a6e86dfaaee64472c00e5f20945729cbebe77f06ce78e08f4098fba41f9d6193c0317e8b60d4b6084acb42d29e3808a3bc372d85e331170fcbf7cc72d0b71c296648b3a4d10f416295d0807aa625cab2744fd9ea8fd223c42537029828bd16be02546f130fd2e33b936d2676e08aed1b73318b750a0167d0". Can you guide me how can i use this message to sign.

Comment: @Topaco: Actually in my case  my message is hex format and also i want to generate signature in hex format.

Comment: Can you post complete test data, i.e. a non-productive key pair (= private and associated public key), a plaintext and the signature generated by X-Cube with the private key? This might help to find out how X-Cube signs your message.

Comment: @Topaco: I updated X-Cube code with actual test data. It has message, private and public key parameters and also expected signature . So we should get same signature in python. for you info i used same private and public key and message in python code. I posted private key because it is just for test purpose.

Comment: With the test data, the details of the X Cube algorithm can be determined so that the appropriate Python code can be implemented, see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the signature is decrypted with the public key without removing the padding:

```py
signature = bytes.fromhex("6bc3a06656842930a247e30d5864b4d819236ba7c68965862ad7dbc4e24af28e86bb531f03358be5fb74777c6086f850caef893f0d6fcc2d0c91ec013693b4ea00b80cd49aac4ecb5f8911afe539ada4a8f3823d1d13e472d1490547c659c7617f3d24087ddb6f2b72096167fc097cab18e9a458fcb634cdce8ee35894c484d7")

modulus = bytes.fromhex("a56e4a0e701017589a5187dc7ea841d156f2ec0e36ad52a44dfeb1e61f7ad991d8c51056ffedb162b4c0f283a12a88a394dff526ab7291cbb307ceabfce0b1dfd5cd9508096d5b2b8b6df5d671ef6377c0921cb23c270a70e2598e6ff89d19f105acc2d3f0cb35f29280e1386b6f64c4ef22e1e1f20d0ce8cffb2249bd9a2137")
public_exponent = bytes.fromhex("010001")

signature_int = int.from_bytes(signature, 'big')
modulus_int = int.from_bytes(modulus, 'big')
public_exponent_int = int.from_bytes(public_exponent, 'big')
decrypted_int = pow(signature_int, public_exponent_int, modulus_int)
decrypted = decrypted_int.to_bytes(128, 'big')
print(decrypted.hex()) # 0001ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff003021300906052b0e03021a05000414cd8b6538cb8e8de566b68bd067569dbf1ee2718e
```

a valid PKCS#1 v1.5 signature results:

```
0001ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff003021300906052b0e03021a05000414cd8b6538cb8e8de566b68bd067569dbf1ee2718e
```

---

The first part of

```
3021300906052b0e03021a05000414 cd8b6538cb8e8de566b68bd067569dbf1ee2718e
```

consists of the ID of the used digest and identifies SHA-1 as the digest applied (see [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#page-47)). When the SHA-1 hash of the used data is generated:

```py
import hashlib
message = bytes.fromhex("cdc87da223d786df3b45e0bbbc721326d1ee2af806cc315475cc6f0d9c66e1b62371d45ce2392e1ac92844c310102f156a0d8d52c1f4c40ba3aa65095786cb769757a6563ba958fed0bcc984e8b517a3d5f515b23b8a41e74aa867693f90dfb061a6e86dfaaee64472c00e5f20945729cbebe77f06ce78e08f4098fba41f9d6193c0317e8b60d4b6084acb42d29e3808a3bc372d85e331170fcbf7cc72d0b71c296648b3a4d10f416295d0807aa625cab2744fd9ea8fd223c42537029828bd16be02546f130fd2e33b936d2676e08aed1b73318b750a0167d0")
hash = hashlib.sha1(message).hexdigest()
print(hash) # cd8b6538cb8e8de566b68bd067569dbf1ee2718e
```

the hash is

```
cd8b6538cb8e8de566b68bd067569dbf1ee2718e
```

which corresponds to the second part and is therefore consistent.

---

This shows that the X Cube code hashes the data with SHA-1 (and *not* SHA-256) and signs the hash with RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 (so *single* hashing of the *raw* data), i.e. the Python counterpart can be implemented as follows:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

# import private key (PEM key generated from the posted RSA parameters)
pkcs8pem = b'''-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'''
private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(pkcs8pem, password=None)

# sign with RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 padding and SHA-1
message = bytes.fromhex("cdc87da223d786df3b45e0bbbc721326d1ee2af806cc315475cc6f0d9c66e1b62371d45ce2392e1ac92844c310102f156a0d8d52c1f4c40ba3aa65095786cb769757a6563ba958fed0bcc984e8b517a3d5f515b23b8a41e74aa867693f90dfb061a6e86dfaaee64472c00e5f20945729cbebe77f06ce78e08f4098fba41f9d6193c0317e8b60d4b6084acb42d29e3808a3bc372d85e331170fcbf7cc72d0b71c296648b3a4d10f416295d0807aa625cab2744fd9ea8fd223c42537029828bd16be02546f130fd2e33b936d2676e08aed1b73318b750a0167d0")
signature = private_key.sign(
    message,
    padding.PKCS1v15(),
    hashes.SHA1()
)

print(signature.hex()) # 6bc3a06656842930a247e30d5864b4d819236ba7c68965862ad7dbc4e24af28e86bb531f03358be5fb74777c6086f850caef893f0d6fcc2d0c91ec013693b4ea00b80cd49aac4ecb5f8911afe539ada4a8f3823d1d13e472d1490547c659c7617f3d24087ddb6f2b72096167fc097cab18e9a458fcb634cdce8ee35894c484d7
```

which provides the expected signature:

```
6bc3a06656842930a247e30d5864b4d819236ba7c68965862ad7dbc4e24af28e86bb531f03358be5fb74777c6086f850caef893f0d6fcc2d0c91ec013693b4ea00b80cd49aac4ecb5f8911afe539ada4a8f3823d1d13e472d1490547c659c7617f3d24087ddb6f2b72096167fc097cab18e9a458fcb634cdce8ee35894c484d7
```

---

**Edit:** Regarding your question from the comment:
To pass the hashed message instead of the message and disable implicit hashing, `Prehashed` must be used (s. [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#signing)):

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import utils
...
# sign with RSA PKCS#1 v1.5 padding and SHA-1 (pass message_hash, disable implicit hashing)
signature = private_key.sign(
    message_hash,
    padding.PKCS1v15(),
    utils.Prehashed(hashes.SHA1()) # apply Prehashed
)
```

where `message_hash` is the hash of the message as bytes-like object that was generated e.g. as follows:

```py
message = bytes.fromhex("cdc87da223d786df3b45e0bbbc721326d1ee2af806cc315475cc6f0d9c66e1b62371d45ce2392e1ac92844c310102f156a0d8d52c1f4c40ba3aa65095786cb769757a6563ba958fed0bcc984e8b517a3d5f515b23b8a41e74aa867693f90dfb061a6e86dfaaee64472c00e5f20945729cbebe77f06ce78e08f4098fba41f9d6193c0317e8b60d4b6084acb42d29e3808a3bc372d85e331170fcbf7cc72d0b71c296648b3a4d10f416295d0807aa625cab2744fd9ea8fd223c42537029828bd16be02546f130fd2e33b936d2676e08aed1b73318b750a0167d0")
digest = hashes.Hash(hashes.SHA1())
digest.update(message)
message_hash = digest.finalize()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. Now the signature same in both python and X-Cube. But i want to generate signature for the data which is already hashed.Because in reality my input data is quite big. could you please provide me the python code to sign on hash value instead of message. I am asking this i might do mistakes in data type conversion handling while generating hash and pass to sign

Comment: @chandrashekar - see the Edit section of my answer please.

Comment: Thank you . it worked. I am able to generate same signature by python script thanks a lot for your support